# SQL: How to update same column across multiple tables?

Tags: sql

I have a query that gets me all the tables I need to update, which all contain a column foo:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'Filter%'
```

How do I combine this with an UPDATE command that will update column foo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SQL SERVER Version:

```
--Test Data
create table [Filter]  ( foo int)
create table [Filter2]  ( foo int)
create table [Filter3]  ( foo int)
insert into [Filter] (foo) values (1)
insert into [Filter2] (foo) values (1)
insert into [Filter3] (foo) values (1)

--use exec and update
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '';
SELECT @sql=@sql+' update '+table_name+' set foo = 2 where foo = 1 ;' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name like 'Filter%'
and TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';
select @sql;
exec(@sql);

--result
select * from [Filter]
```

[image]

DB Test Link:
 [sql-how-to-update-same-column-across-multiple-tables](http://rextester.com/MFQ16118)